# How to create *.run./*.bin file in Debian based distros

Tags: debian, software-installation, packaging

AMD distributes the Catalyst drivers as a ****.run*** file that when ran extracts itself, builds and then installs the [driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86). Thing is the driver needs a patch for it to build successfully. I want to apply the patch and zip up or recreate the *run* file so that I won't have to do it over and over the next time.

Btw, the run file is not purely shell script commands, it has a section with binary code that possibly recreates the files and folders when extracted.

Answer (score 3):

AMD distributes an executable file which you are meant to run as root to perform the installation. Its name and that that name ends with is pretty much irrelevant.

That file, being an executable, can work any way AMD chooses to make it work. It can be a shell script (I gather that it is) or a binary executable or theoretically anything else executable. So there really does not exist any generalized way of editing such a thing while preserving its structure.

> the run file is not purely shell script commands

Yes, such vendor-supplied scripts that intend to install software by mucking around your system generally include a means of extracting a binary archive (like a `tar`) that is encoded and embedded inside the shell script. This is what you mean by "it has a section with binary code".

Again, though, the way in which the vendor chose to encode and embed that archive is completely arbitrary. It could be a base64-encoded tar file, or anything else, really.

If you want to edit the file supplied by AMD, you will have to examine it to see how it works, then probably decode and extract some part of it, apply the patch, archive and re-encode the result, and replace the original embedded contents with yours.

Bottom line: this type of ad-hoc software installation method isn't well structured like a Debian or RPM package would be, and can't be manipulated with the same kind of regularity and standardization.

Answer (score 0):

The software to use is makeself.sh, distributed by megastep, which is downloaded as makeself.run. Here's a URL to download the package: http://stephanepeter.com/makeself/, where the archive creation options are explained. I used it to patch nvidia driver files and recreate the .run file. It will execute an existing installation program within the archive.